# Performance Testing WCF services with Content-Type application/soap+msbin1

Tags: performance, wcf, performance-testing, wcf-binding

We have WCF services with binary encoding and we are attempting to do performance testing after the .net Framework upgrade to .Net 4.8

We have learnt that Binary-Encoding is not supported in non .Net based client

Wanted to check if someone managed to use any script, plugins, libraries or something different to integrate binary-encoding in any of the performance testing tools/framework such as Load Runner / SOAP UI etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use WCF performance counters to perform performance tests on WCF. For more information about WCF performance counters, you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/performance-counters/

Comment: @DingPeng: Thanks for the link and its helpful. However how do we simulate the load is what we are exploring